# Cargo: use of unstable library feature 'scoped_threads'

Tags: ubuntu, rust, build, rust-cargo

I have this repo cloned on my Ubuntu 22.04 instance: https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/ubuntu-build

and I'm trying to run:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
sudo make image PROFILE=kstr-sama5d27
```

I receive the following error:

> error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'scoped_threads'    -->
> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cargo-deb-1.41.3/src/data.rs:128:5
> | 128 |     std::thread::scope(move |s| {
> |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> |
> = note: see issue #93203 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203 for more information
>
> error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'scoped_threads'    -->
> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cargo-deb-1.41.3/src/data.rs:130:29
> | 130 |         let hash_thread = s.spawn(move || {
> |                             ^^^^^
> |
> = note: see issue #93203 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203 for more information
>
> error[E0658]: use of unstable library feature 'scoped_threads'    -->
> /root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/cargo-deb-1.41.3/src/data.rs:162:24
> | 162 |         Ok(hash_thread.join().unwrap())
> |                        ^^^^
> |
> = note: see issue #93203 https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93203 for more information
>
> For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
> error: could not compile `cargo-deb` due to 3 previous errors warning:
> build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish... error: failed to
> compile `gpt-manipulator v0.1.0 (/home/davidg/kstr-ubuntu-build/build-kstr-sama5d27/gpt-manipulator)`,
> intermediate artifacts can be found at
> `/home/davidg/kstr-ubuntu-build/build-kstr-sama5d27/gpt-manipulator/target`
> make: *** [Makefile:106: gpt-manipulator] Error 101

There's been no change to the source code since the last time this worked so my suspicion is   something external has changed. I performed `grep -r "thread::scope" .` in the repo and found no uses of this unstable feature.

The gpt-manipulator submodule repo having the build error is  https://gitlab.conclusive.pl/devices/gpt-manipulator and I can `cargo build` from this repo without issue.

Note that my environment is prepared using `sudo apt-get install bc libssl-dev cargo gdisk mtools`. This installs rust&cargo system-wide and allows sudo to access it  (needed by `sudo make image`). I read that using `rustup` install method I can switch to nightly and allow the unstable feature but installing this way sudo can't find the binaries.

`cargo --version` and `rustc --version` both report 1.61.0

How can I successfully build this?

Answer (score 3):

Scoped threads have been stabilized in 1.63 so some dependency might be using it now. If you're running an earlier compiler it will complain about that usage though. A `rustup update` or the equivalent for what you use to update Rust should fix this.

Comment: Looks like the latest version of [`rustc` in the Ubuntu apt repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rustc) is 1.61.0, so they will have to switch to rustup.

Comment: So I guess this means I need to figure out how to install `rustup` for the root user (https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/1085) or adjust the build process to not require `sudo` or wait for 1.63.0 via aptitude.

Comment: I'm still unclear how I'm able to build this successfully with 1.61.0 when running `cargo build --release` just on gpt-manipulator versus this occurring as a step in the make process

Comment: It's actually the `cargo install cargo-deb` command that is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The command that's failing is actually `cargo install cargo-deb`. It appears the latest version uses scoped threads.

As a workaround, you can install a specific older version:

```
cargo install cargo-deb --version 1.28.2
```

Might want to use `1.28.2` to match the version you say is in `Cargo.toml`, otherwise it looks like `1.40.5` is the last version not using `std::thread::scope`.

Comment: cargo.toml pins the cargo-deb version to 1.28.2 and this is what is installed when I run `cargo build` on the gpt-manipulator repo directly. For some reason `sudo make image PROFILE=kstr-sama5d27` on the parent repo is trying to install cargo-deb version 1.41.3

Comment: The `cargo-deb` installed by `cargo install cargo-deb` has nothing to do with the version in your `Cargo.toml` or `Cargo.lock`. `cargo install cargo-deb` installs the `cargo-deb` package as a global binary.

Comment: @davegravy the makefile has `cargo install cargo-deb`. Have you tried running that command yourself?

Comment: do you mean README.md? I have tried and it fails with same error (tries to compile cargo-deb@1.41.3). `cargo install cargo-deb@1.38.2` fails with "could not find `cargo-deb@1.38.2` in registry `crates-io` with version `*`"

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I forgot it doesn't work like `npm`. See the edit

Answer (score -1):

Per @cafce25's answer, scoped threads are stabilized in 1.63.0, however at present apt is limited to supplying 1.61.0.

To obtain a version >= 1.63.0 that can be run with sudo:

1. `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sudo sh`
2. append secure_path in /etc/sudoers with `:/root/.cargo/bin`

Comment: Don't install rustup globally this way. Instead install it for your regular user and build your target as this user. And _never_ pipe the output of `curl` directly into `sudo` without at least eyeballing it to make sure it doesn't do anything it shouldn't.